# What is the best way to count page views in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

And by best I mean most efficient, right now placing this on my post.php file is the only thing I can think of:

```
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE posts SET views + 1 WHERE id = '$id' ");
```

is there a better way, a method that would consume less server resources. I ask because if this was a small app I would have no problem with the above, but I am trying to build something that will be used by a lot of people and I want to be as query conscious as possible.

Comment: You could skip PHP/MySQL and use files instead.

Comment: Just curius as to why you are reinventing the wheel, when there are free services to do this, which also provide fancy reports. I use 3rd party s/w as often as possible, to free up more time for me to develop my actual app. That said, I advise getting open source in case the service disappers; you don't want to be left high & dry. But things like user management are such a common paradigm that you can be sure that someone else has already solved them (and I always reckon that they have doen so better than I could :-)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're interested in conserving resources and still using SQL for reporting, and precise # doesn't matter, you could try sampling like this (modify sample rate to suit your scale):

```
$sample_rate = 100;
if(mt_rand(1,$sample_rate) == 1) {
    $query = mysql_query(" UPDATE posts SET views = views + {$sample_rate} WHERE id = '{$id}' ");
    // execute query, etc
}
```

Comment: Depending on how big "a lot of users" is, it may be beneficial to avoid MySQL on any tables that could get long.  A good rule of thumb is this: *If any collection (table) can get past 10 million records during your app's lifetime, you should probably not store that collection in MySQL*.  I recommend investigating MongoDB and Membase before it's too late!

Comment: @dorkitude, do you have any further information / reference for this rule? We have tables in the tens of billions of rows without problem. Not saying that MongoDB / memcached aren't a good resource, just wondering where we can find more information.

Comment: Tens of **billions** in a mysql table?  Are you sure of that?

Comment: IMHO better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762527/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-page-views-in-php-mysql/6007631#6007631

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could someone explain what this does? It doesn't make sense to me. What is this good for?

Comment: Someone please explain this solution, i can't seem to understand what this does..

Comment: @Suyash This code is generating a random number between 1 and 100 - IF and only if the random number turns out to be '1', then the database value holding the view count will be incremented by 100. The general idea behind this is that, in theory, it should take 100 tries to hit the number '1' - and so the view count is more or less correct without the constant need to query the database.

Comment: but isn't that based on some serious assumptions? i mean for all we know the random function could easily update 5 times in 10 tries. But i get the point now. Thanks.

Comment: It just uses probability. Sure there may be examples of results being way off at the beginning but generally the views will be correct - and the more views that come through, the more accurate this will be overall. The other point is that view count isn't such an essential part of the data in most apps.

Comment: If you check how many views post currently has, it makes sense to divide it by number (e.g. 1000) and use result as `$sample_rate`. This provides some more dynamic. Popular posts views will be less counted, 
because the greater values they have, the less important one unit will be.

Answer (score 18):

If memcache is an option in your server environment, here's another cool way to sample, but also keep up with the precise number (unlike my other answer):

```
function recordPostPageView($page_id) {
    $memcache = new Memcached(); // you could also pull this instance from somewhere else, if you want a bit more efficiency*

    $key = "Counter for Post {$page_id}";

    if(!$memcache->get($key)) {
        $memcache->set($key, 0);
    }

    $new_count = $memcache->increment($key);

    // you could uncomment the following if you still want to notify mysql of the value occasionally
    /*
    $notify_mysql_interval = 100;
    if($new_count % $notify_mysql_interval == 0) {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET views = {$new_count} WHERE id = '{$page_id}' ");
        // execute query, etc
    }
    */

    return $new_count;
}
```

- And don't mind purists crying foul about Singletons.  Or you could pass it into this function, if you're more purist than pragmatist :)

Comment: setting up memcached and the confusion between memcache and memcached aside, this was an extremely elegant solution and the benchmarking results are very happy as well! Thanks for the awesome info.

Comment: This works perfectly, as an improvement pass the count value from the database into the function as an extra variable, then use this value to set the memcache key. This way your counter stays in sync (plus or minus your interval value) if memcache is restarted.

Comment: @paj Or you could simply flush your Memcache on each cronjob and start afresh, only adding up the count in the db by using count= count + memcache(getkey)

Answer (score 6):

IMHO best solution is to have views_count stored inside memory (memcached, whatever),
and do updates in memory. (Of course updates have to be synchronized)

Then you can use cron script which will push those values to db. (after some time - seconds, minutes, whatever.)

Answer (score 6):

in the database there is only one column `ip` with primary key defined and then store ip in database using PHP code below:

Connection file :

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn,"DB_NAME");
if(!$db)
{
    echo "Connection failed";
}
?>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$insert="INSERT INTO  `id928751_photography`.`ip` (`ip`)VALUES ('$ip');";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
?>
```

show count :

```
<?php
$select="SELECT COUNT(ip) as count from ip;";
$run= mysqli_query($conn,$select);
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
echo $res['count'];
?>
```

using this method in the database store all server ip

NOTE: only server ip can store or count not device ip

Answer (score 4):

You could keep a counter-array in cache (like APC or Memcache) and increase the counter for certain posts in that. Then store the updates once a while. You might loose some views if a cache-reset occures

Other solution would be to keep a separate table for visits only (Field: postid, visits). That is the fasters you can get from mysql. Try to use InnoDB engine, since it provides row-level-locking!

Answer (score 4):

You can also check these lines of code. I think it will be helpful because you can achieve your goal with just a text file. It does not require any database activity.

```html
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";
// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}
// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);
// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}
echo "You are visitor number $counterVal to this site";
```

Answer (score 1):

This way show how many actual people viewed your website not just how many times they viewed your website.

**Step1: Connecting to MySQL**

dbconfig.php

```
try
{
    // Returns DB instance or create initial connection
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};port={$DB_port};dbname={$DB_name};charset=utf8mb4",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Step2: Creating MySQL table**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `unique_visitors`
--

CREATE TABLE `unique_visitors` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `ip` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `views` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Step3: Create a visitor counter by using IP address.**

```
<?php
    require_once("dbconfig.php");
    // Returns current date in YYYY-MM-DD format
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    // Stores remote user ip address
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // Query for selecting record of current date from the table
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM unique_visitors WHERE date=:date");
    $stmt->execute(['date' => $date]);

    if(count($stmt->fetchAll()) === 0){
        // Block will execute when there is no record of current date in the database table
        $data = [
            'date' => $date,
            'ip' => $userIP,
        ];
        // SQL query for inserting new record into the database table with current date and user IP address
        $sql = "INSERT INTO unique_visitors (date, ip) VALUES (:date, :ip)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
    }else{
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // Will execute when current IP is not in database
        if(!preg_match('/'.$userIP.'/i',$row['ip'])){
            // Combines previous and current user IP address with a separator for updating in the database
            $newIP = "$row[ip] $userIP";
            $data = [
                'ip' => $newIP,
                'date' => $date,
            ];
            $sql = "UPDATE unique_visitors SET ip=:ip, views=views+1 WHERE date=:date";
            $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: ok this is the barebones solution but ip field eventually will get large if many different ips visit pages on same date. IMO better add a new row each row should have one ip

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";
// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}
// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);
// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}
echo "You are visitor number $counterVal to this site";
```