# updating post views each time a post is viewed with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know if this is allowed, but I need clarification on a solution given to a question.

[What is the best way to count page views in PHP/MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762527/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-page-views-in-php-mysql)

I have the exact question. I just have no idea how the solution makes any sense, here is the solution:

```
$sample_rate = 100;
if(mt_rand(1,$sample_rate) == 1) {
    $query = mysql_query(" UPDATE posts 
                              SET views = views + {$sample_rate} 
                            WHERE id = '{$id}' ");
    // execute query, etc
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here mt_rand() generate random number between 1 to 100, so probability of that number to be one is 1/100. 
If this generate 1, we are increasing value of views by 100. 
So, effective increase in database per view 
          = ( Probability of increasing view ) * (increase  in database )
          = (1/ 100 )* 100
          = 1

So in long run it will increase database value by 1 for each view.

This is tread-off between accuracy of post and speed. As MySQL query are more time extensive than PHP rand function calls.

Answer (score 1):

For each user that views a page, a random number between 1 and 100 ($sample_rate) is generated. If the number equals 1, then the database is updated by the amount of possible values (sample rate).

This is simply a sampling technique used to save resources. This is a common technique used for larger websites.

If you are running a smaller operation, you should simply update the database each time the page is viewed, as oppose to using a sampling method.

Comment: That makes no sense. so, 100k people visit your site and you record only 100 visitors?

Comment: @phil the chance of generating a 1 is 1/100. For each 1 that is generated, 100 views are added to the database. So no, in theory (each view is dependent), the count should be close to accurate. If you have lower traffic, you need to lower the upper bound.

Comment: so if you want to add 1 to each view, you change the 100 to 1? I am also confused. Per your explanation, each page view will record 100 views instead, based on the code above?